# How to insert text and value from checkbox in datalist into sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, checkbox, datalist

i have datalist filled by checkbox. the code like this

the form

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataListTest" runat="server" OnPreRender="PreTes">
        <ItemTemplate>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server"></asp:Label>                                        
        </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblsubheader" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="subhd" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("sub_category") %>' />
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbNameAccess" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("name_access") %>' />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hd" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("name_category") %>' />
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

the code to get data from database

```
private void ShowDataList()
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "Select access.id_access, access.nama_access, jenis_access.id_jenis_access ,jenis_access.nama_jenis_access as 'nama_jenis', sub_jenis.nama_sub_jenis as 'sub_jenis',sub_jenis.id_sub_jenis "+
                 "FROM access LEFT JOIN detil_access ON access.id_access = detil_access.id_access "+
                 "LEFT JOIN jenis_access ON detil_access.id_jenis_access = jenis_access.id_jenis_access "+
                 "LEFT JOIN sub_jenis ON detil_access.id_sub_jenis = sub_jenis.id_sub_jenis "+
                 "ORDER BY jenis_access.id_jenis_access";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    dt = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(dt);
    DataListTest.DataSource = dt;
    DataListTest.DataBind();
}
```

the code to show data from database into datalist and show it as Checkbox

```
 protected void PreTes(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string temp = ""; 
    string subtemp ="";
    foreach (DataList item in DataListTest.Items)
    {
        Label objLabel = item.FindControl("lblHeader") as Label;
        Label subjenis = item.FindControl("lblsubheader") as Label;
        CheckBox objName = item.FindControl("cbCountryName") as CheckBox;
        HiddenField objHD = item.FindControl("hd") as HiddenField;
        HiddenField subobjHD = item.FindControl("subhd") as HiddenField;

        if (temp != objHD.Value)
        {                                    
             temp = objHD.Value;
             objLabel.Text = temp + "<br/>";                                   
        }
        if (subtemp != subobjHD.Value)
        {
            subtemp = subobjHD.Value;
            subjenis.Text = subtemp+"<br/>";
        }

    }
}
```

the code for insert into sql

```
private void InsertActivationDetail()
{
    // get idActivation
    int MaxActivationId = GetGenerateActivationID();
    //

    foreach (DataList objitem in DataListTest.Items)
    {
        if (objitem.Selected)
        {
            conn.Open();
            sql = "INSERT INTO detil_activation (id_activation_access, id_jenis_access, id_access, " +
                  "others_all, others_nama_access, call_back_to, reason_any_number, description_other_jenis_access, " +
                  "reason_others_jenis_access) VALUES ('" +
                  MaxActivationId + "', (select id_jenis_access from access where id_access = '" +
                  objitem.Value + "'), '" + objitem.Value + "',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

my question is "How to insert id and name(text and value) from checkbox into database sql server"

i think the problem is around function InsertActivationDetail(). because i have red underline on it. Would you mind to help me please ?

FYI = i'm a newbie in here also programmer.

Comment: On what basis you are inserting the data, I mean based on check box selection. how the result should be. because this line foreach (DataList item in DataListTest.Items) throws error it should be foreach (DataListItem item in DataListTest.Items). can you elaborate it would be helpful

Comment: the result must be get the name and value(id), base on checkbox selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Modified your Method a little. Your are not getting the CheckBox within your DataList.

```
private void InsertActivationDetail()
{
    // get idActivation
    int MaxActivationId = GetGenerateActivationID();
    //

    foreach (DataListItem objitem in DataListTest.Items)
    {
        CheckBox cbNameAccess = (CheckBox)objitem.FindControl("cbNameAccess");
            if (cbNameAccess != null)
            {
                if (cbNameAccess.Checked==true)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    sql = "INSERT INTO detil_activation (id_activation_access, id_jenis_access, id_access, " +
                          "others_all, others_nama_access, call_back_to, reason_any_number, description_other_jenis_access, " +
                          "reason_others_jenis_access) VALUES ('" +
                          MaxActivationId + "', (select id_jenis_access from access where id_access = '" +
                          cbNameAccess.Text + "'), '" + cbNameAccess.Text + "',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cbNameAccess.Text in sql query, it mean to gets the text shown on form right ? i just try it but it didn't work. It says "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItem' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList'." on foreach() statement

Comment: Did you use the entire method I copied here? I've done few changes there. try replacing your method with what I've given in my answer.

Comment: Note the change in the foreach. I've used DataListItem instead of DataList

Comment: oh, i'm sorry. i was wrong. it's done now. but i have one last problem. with cbNameAccss.Text didn't catch the id of it. example cbNameAccess.Text = Telephone. in database Telephone has id, lets say '123' i want to catch '123' and send it to database.

Comment: have a hidden field (say test) to hold your id just like you "hd" hidden field. Then find the hidden field as we did for check box like this. HiddenField test = (HiddenField)objitem.FindControl("test"); Then use test.Text instead of cbNameAccess.Text

Comment: vote and accept the answer since it solved your initial issue

Comment: i just add HiddenField id_access = (HiddenField)objitem.FindControl("id_access"); bellow CheckBox cbCountryName = ...... But it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: in form i type like thsi <asp:HiddenField ID="test" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("id_access") %>' />. which part i have mistake ?

Comment: it's done now. no errors, but when i check database,the value is NULL. my query sql = "INSERT INTO detil_activation (id_activation_access, id_jenis_access, id_access, " +
                          "others_all, others_nama_access, call_back_to, reason_any_number, description_other_jenis_access, " +
                          "reason_others_jenis_access) VALUES ('" +
                          MaxActivationId + "', (select id_jenis_access from detil_access where id_access = '" +
                          id_access.Value + "'), '" + id_access.Value + "',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)";

Comment: You'll have to post this as another question. I just solved your initial issue. We can't keep going like this. Vote and Accept this answer and post your DB question separately.