# How to catch data from table (dynamically to database)

Tags: c#, sql, checkbox

I have table dynamically to database and fulfilled by checkboxes. 
This is what is on my html:

```html
<table width="800px" style="margin-right: 42px" border="0">   
<tr>
<asp:Table CssClass="left" ID="left" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" />              
<asp:Table CssClass="right" ID="right" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" />
<asp:Table CssClass="other" ID="other" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal"></asp:Table>
</tr>
</table>
```

And this is my code behind to show or get data from database also print table dynamically to database (tr and td).

```cs
private void ShowDataList()
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "Select access.id_access as 'id_access',access.status, access.nama_access, jenis_access.id_jenis_access as 'idJenisAccess' , " +
                 "jenis_access.nama_jenis_access as 'nama_jenis', sub_jenis.nama_sub_jenis as 'sub_jenis',sub_jenis.id_sub_jenis "+
                 "FROM access LEFT JOIN detil_access ON access.id_access = detil_access.id_access "+
                 "LEFT JOIN jenis_access ON detil_access.id_jenis_access = jenis_access.id_jenis_access "+
                 "LEFT JOIN sub_jenis ON detil_access.id_sub_jenis = sub_jenis.id_sub_jenis "+
                 "ORDER BY jenis_access.id_jenis_access";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    string jenis = string.Empty;
    string subjenis = string.Empty;       
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (jenis == string.Empty || dr["nama_jenis"].ToString() != jenis)
        {
            tc.CssClass = "cb";
            jenis = dr["nama_jenis"].ToString();
            tr = new TableRow(); //cetak <tr> kosongan
            tc = new TableCell(); // cetak <td> kosongan
            tc.ColumnSpan = 3; // menggabungkan 3 kolom jadi 1
            tc.Text = dr["nama_jenis"].ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(tc); // masukin <td> ke <tr>               
            if (dr["nama_jenis"].ToString() == "Business System")
            {
                right.Rows.Add(tr); // jika nama jenis == Business System maka taruh di tabel kanan
            }
            else if (dr["nama_jenis"].ToString() == "Others")
            {
                other.Rows.Add(tr);// jika nama jenis == Other taruh di table other                    
            }
            else
            {
                left.Rows.Add(tr); // sisanya kiri
            }
        }
        if ((subjenis == string.Empty || subjenis != dr["sub_jenis"].ToString()) && dr["nama_jenis"].ToString() == "Business System") // sub jenisnya
        {
            subjenis = dr["sub_jenis"].ToString(); 
            tr = new TableRow();
            tc = new TableCell();
            tc.ColumnSpan = 3;
            tc.Text = dr["sub_jenis"].ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            right.Rows.Add(tr);
        }

        // bikin kolom untuk check box nya
        tr = new TableRow();
        tc = new TableCell();            
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        tc.CssClass = "cb";
        //cb.AutoPostBack = true;
        cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckBox1_CheckedChanged);
        cb.ID = dr["id_access"].ToString() + "," + dr["id_sub_jenis"].ToString();
        tc.Controls.Add(cb);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc); // satu <td> di masukin ke <tr> (td yang 1)

        //bikin kolom untuk nama aksesnya
        tc = new TableCell();
        tc.Text = dr["nama_access"].ToString();

        if (dr["status"].ToString() == "1") // kalo status 1 maka langsung di add, tapi kalo bukan 1 di colspan
        {
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            tc = new TableCell();
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = dr["id_access"].ToString() + "," + dr["id_sub_jenis"].ToString();
            tc.Controls.Add(tb); // satu <td> dimasukin ke <tr> (td yang ke 2)
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            tr.CssClass = "cb";
            //satu <td> di masukin ke <tr> (td yang ke 3) --> makanya di form sebelah kiri bisa ada 3 <td> dlm 1 <tr>
            //1 <tr> = 1 baris.
            // 1 baris ada 3 kolom.
            //beda baris maka = new <tr>
        }
        else
        {
            tc.ColumnSpan = 2; // di colspan (untuk yang gak punya teksbox)
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        }
        if (dr["nama_jenis"].ToString() == "Business System")
        {
            right.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
        else if (dr["nama_jenis"].ToString() == "Others")
        {
            other.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
        else
        {
            left.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

and this is the checkbox code.

```cs
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cbs = (CheckBox)sender;        
    if (cbs.Checked)
    {
        bt.Add(cbs.ID);
    }
    else
    {
        bt.RemoveAll(p => p == cbs.Text);
    }
}
```

My question is, how to get the value or data in my table if my table like that ?
example, I want to catch the id of checked checkbox.
If I check checkbox then I must catch the id of it; every checkbox has 2 id: id_access and idJenisAccess. If I check 2 checkboxes it must be 4 id. So, I mean how to catch the id from the my table?
( I prefer to make a new function for do it )

Comment: Help me please, I'm on deadline T_T

Comment: Where is problem in your code ?

Comment: my code isn't problem. my problem is How to get id from my table in showdatalist() function. this is may be reference for my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904150/how-to-insert-text-and-value-from-checkbox-in-datalist-into-sql-server

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926180/why-my-value-is-null-when-inserted-into-database

Comment: i wanna make form to insert activation access. before i use this method, i used to datalist. but it's hard to separate into 3 column. so i try to use this method, print rows of table by code in .cs. but I don't know how to catch the id of my checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will get id of checkboxes at a button click after the table is filled with data nad checkboxes in it than try this

```
foreach (TableRow tr in left.Rows)
    {
        foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Cells)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in tc.Controls)
            {
                CheckBox chk = ctrl as CheckBox;
                if (chk != null)
                {
                    if (chk.Checked)
                    {
                        string id = chk.ID;//Checkbox id
                        string text = chk.Text;//Checkbox Text
                        YourSaveMethodHere();
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

And if you want to get only checkboxes than break loop after you have got your desired result.

Comment: You can make new function for this and call that function on button click.

Comment: @azalikaayla Have you checked it ?

Comment: Now what is confusing you ? And tell one thing that will you save the id of checkboxes in DB or what will you do with these ids ?

Comment: case closed, I choose to back to my previous method (using Datalist)
it is too confused me. thank you for your help @Mairaj Ahmad.

Comment: You are welcome and if you face any problem please let us know.

Comment: You can also get this down to a single `foreach` if you do `var controls = left.Rows.SelectMany(row => row.Cells).SelectMany(cell => cell.Controls); foreach(var control in controls) { ... }`. That should be better than triple-nested loops.